# ( Django ) upload file always failed

Tags: python, django, html

I'm trying to upload a file to server with Django, but the `form.is_valid` is always return Flase. Then I have output the form value as follow presented.

print form in views.py

```
<tr><th><label for="id_country">country:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="country" value="DE" required id="id_country" maxlength="200" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_email">email:</label></th><td><input type="email" name="email" value="123456789@example.com" required id="id_email" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_filetoupload">fileToUpload:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input type="file" name="filetoupload" required id="id_filetoupload" /></td>
    </tr>
```

form.py

```
from django import forms


class UserInfo(forms.Form):
    country = forms.CharField(label='country', max_length=200)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='email')
    filetoupload = forms.FileField(label='fileToUpload')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from loadfileweb.views import receiveinfo

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/', receiveinfo),
    url(r'^home/submit', receiveinfo)
]
```

views.py

```
    def receiveinfo(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserInfo(request.POST, request.FILES)
            print "form info"
            print form
            print form.is_valid()
            if form.is_valid():
                # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
                country = form.cleaned_data['country']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                print email
                print "------------ get email -----------"



                # redirect to a new URL:
                return HttpResponse('/thanks/')
            else:
                print "-----   form isn't valid   -------"

                return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            print "--------- request.method != 'POST'------------"
            form = UserInfo()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

home.html

```
<form class='UserInfo' action="submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                    E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autofocus><br>
                    {{ form.email.errors}}<br>
                    Country: <input list="countrycode" name="country">
                    {{ form.country.errors}}<br>
                    <datalist id="countrycode">
                        <option value="DE">
                        <option value="ES">
                        <option value="FR">
                        <option value="IT">
                        <option value="UK">
                        <option value="JP">
                        <option value="CA">
                        <option value="USA">
                    </datalist>
                    <br>
                    Select a file to upload:
                    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" ><br>
                    {{ form.filetoupload.errors}}<br>
                    <input type="submit"><br>
                </form>
```

I have searched on google and many forums and still have problem with it. Hope for your help, Thanks!

Comment: Can you put the print of form.errors after .is_valid() return False?

Comment: yes, the output result is '<ul class="errorlist"><li>filetoupload<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>' . But I definitely have chosen a file to upload,  I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) make the file field optional - You either have to make your filetoupload field in form as non mandatory with `required=False` or upload the file before submitting!

Because, it is clear that the mandatory (with `This field is required.` in the `print forms` in views.py that you have shared)

2) to make your file field mandatory, you need to modify `filetoupload` in your form to match the name attribute of your html element or vice versa to do the trick!

```
class UserInfo(forms.Form):
    country = forms.CharField(label='country', max_length=200)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='email')
    filetoUpload = forms.FileField(label='fileToUpload')
```

Comment: Actually, this web program need a file to porcess, so the filetoupload field should be requied. And I also sure I have chosen a file to upload. The program dosen't recognize.

Comment: how come. the error message clearly says that you havent chosen the file! try to check in inspect element of your browser after choosing your file whether the file location is mapped to the element!

Comment: Don't know how. I have changed required to 'False', and it works. I can get the file now. But that makes me can't sure whether user upload a file.

Comment: It is a mandatory field, remove the required=False part and try to submit the form again by uploading the file properly. the file wouldnt have been properly uploaded the first time may be.

Comment: For testing purpose you can have required attribute  in your html element and remove the required=False in your forms.py and try submitting after uploading the file. And if you were able to submit properly and the `print form` still contains the `This field is required` we can look into this further

Comment: ok, I have done what you said. When I  `print request.FILES['fileToUpload']`, it show as 'filename.xls'. And the `form.is_valid ` keeps false. `form.error` is same as before.

Comment: This is it. `filetoupload ` and the name of your html input element is `filetoUpload `. Notice the caps `U` . rename the name in html element and that should do the trick!

Comment: Awesome! If you feel an solution fixes your problem, kindly accept and upvote it so that anyone else who faces a similar issue might make use of it!

Answer (score 0):

1.You have not saved your form.
2.You can try :

```
if form.is_valid():

    temp = form.save(commit=False)
    country = form.cleaned_data['country']
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    temp.save()
    return HttpResponse('/thanks/')
```